# Xcode long compile .m

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compilation

I have Accessories.m:

```
#import "Accessories.h"

@implementation Accessories

+(NSArray*)getItemsFor:(NSInteger)n
{
    NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray array];
    Accessories *item;
    BOOL en = true;

    //From this
    item = [[Accessories alloc] init];
    [item setImage: @""];
    [item setName: en ? @"" : @""];
    [item setPriceName: @""];
    [item setLevel: en ? @"" : @""];
    [item setPositive: en ? @"" : @""];
    [item setNegative: en ? @"" : @""];
    [item setDescrip: en ? @"" : @""];
    [item setText: en ? @"" : @""];
    [item setTrivia: en ? @"" : @""];
    [item setBugs: en ? @"" : @""];
    [item setWornBy: en ? @"" : @""];
    [item setSlot: en ? @"" : @""];
    [item setEquipRegion: en ? @"" : @""];
    [item setContributedBy: en ? @"" : @""];
    [item setReleased: en ? @"" : @""];
    [item setAvailability: en ? @"" : @""];
    [items addObject:item];
    //Up here it is repeat 1200

    return items;
}

@end
```

And I have this:
[image]
It lasts for about 7 hours.
I used to be able to set Optimization Level to None [-O0], but now this does not work.

Comment: It's repeated 1200 times as in you copy-pasted that block 1200 times? Why aren't you using a loop?

Comment: Each block contains unique settings.

Comment: You should store them in core data or a plist or something and load it at runtime.  I guess the compiler doesn't like methods that are 20000 lines long.  7 hours seems pretty long though, you could try submitting a bug report to llvm

Comment: How I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More likely than not, it is taking so long to compile because the compiler is using a ton of memory to compile what is a pathologically odd bit of code.

You could file a bug, if you want.

To fix;  use a loop and read the data from a file.  Even a plist would work.  Or you could prepopulate a coredata database on your Mac and ship it with your app.

(I really hope that 1200 copies of those lines are machine generated!!!)